# One inject from multiple constants - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular constant as an configuration file for my services, my problem is that this file can become huge and i am would like to separate the configuration into multiple files. But i don´t want to create a new Angular constant that i need to inject in the services that uses constants.

Is there a way to have only one main constant file that requires all the other files so that there is only one inject into the services? Or is it possibly to create one constant from all js files in a specific folder?

Other solutions to this problem would also be very helpful.

Comment: could you write another service that merges them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$provide.decorator` for that:

```
$provide.decorator('yourSettings', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
     $delegate.newProp = 'new value';
     return delegate;
}]);
```

See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator).

Comment: I have tried using $provide.decorator now but i don´t really know how to get it to work. Is this how it is suppose to be used or and is it even possible to use it with constants?
http://plnkr.co/edit/mMTRSVHz9yMLiMsHfqJw?p=preview